# Facebook PHP SDK storing session cookie. How can I stop this?

Tags: facebook, cookies, facebook-php-sdk, session-cookies

I unfortunately live in the EU and have this horrible cookie legislation.

See below my application instance.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $fb_app_id,
    'secret' => $fb_secret,
    'cookie' => true
));
```

Unfortunately this stores a cookie called... `PHPSESSID`

How can I prevent this cookie from ever downloading???

I tried this but did not work...

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $fb_app_id,
    'secret' => $fb_secret,
    'cookie' => false
));
```

Any help would be amazing thanks.

Comment: About what EU cookie legislation are you speaking??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to reimplement the [`Facebook`](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/facebook.php) class from the facebook sdk. The meat of the functionality in the Base_Facebook class, and the `Facebook` one only implements the session persistence (calling [`session_start()`](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/facebook.php#L60) in it's `__constructor` that creates that cookie).

You will also have to find a new way to make session available for your users. PHP support sessionid passed around in URLs with:

```
ini_set("session.use_cookies", 0);
ini_set("session.use_trans_sid", 1);
```

but that isn't really a good idea (non malicious url copy-paste makes it easy to steal sessions).

Comment: So all in all it's not a good idea? - I am literally touching the surface with this facebook app instance - using it for some very basic features.

Comment: From technical standpoint, I don't know how could you replace cookies painlessly. I'm really not sure about the legal stuff, but if i recall correctly with a privacy policy document that explains how you will use the user's data and a checkbox that will say "Yes i allow them to use cookies to track my info" at login should do it for the lawyers.